# Using 3xx codes to perform redirect for directory level resources

Tags: browser, redirect, resources, directory

I have hosted a local server on my system on port 80. And I have few other local servers running on port 8080/8081/8082.. And I want to redirect by requests from port 80 to these ports based on the directory they access.

So for example if request is like http:// 127.0.0.1/test1/... I want request to be redirected to http:// 127.0.0.1:8080/test1/....

Is there a way in which I can just return 301 once and then browser understands that all the requests with http:// 127.0.0.1/test1/ prefix all automatically should be redirected to new URL. I do not want to send redirect call for every resource within test1 folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you are describing using 3xx HTTP response codes. You do however, have several options:

1. Use a rewrite module
2. Create a relay, to simply connect the client to the correct server
3. Setup your server to send a 301 code for every url that starts with a certain path (test1, for example).

You'll need to provide more information about what type of servers you're using to get a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Currently I am using the option 3 that you have suggested. But it always ends up into 1 extra IPC. My main intention was to avoid that extra IPC. Even option 1 and 2 would require the same number of IPCs. I am using lighttpd. Irrespective of the server I wanted a way to solve the issue with HTTP codes and browser default behavior for these Http codes.

Comment: The only way I see to prevent the IPC at all is to only use relative and root URLs in the application server. The browser won't change the host, so it will redirect to port 8080 and stay there.